# DevPartner Profiler Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, profiler, devpartner

I used to have DevPartner Profiler Community Edition installed on my machine, which was free to use indefinitely and was compatible with Visual Studio 2003.

After I have rebuild my machine and downloaded a newer version (version 8.1) of the software, it turns out it is actually a 45 day trial eventhough it is still called a Community Edition.

I have tried looking for an older version, but haven't been able to find it.

Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billy, Compuware retired the Community Edition profiler years ago and pulled it from any web sites. That profiler was used as a marketing tool. Folks were supposed to use the profiler then request an upgrade to the full DevPartner Studio suite. Because that didn't really pan out they yanked down the profiler. Under Micro Focus, you can now obtain the full suite but license just the profiler at a much lower price point than the full suite. I suggest you look at http://www.microfocus.com under MF Developer at the different offerings. Shameless plug: I work on the DevPartner team. We are releasing our 64-bit profiler editions in version 10.5 on February 4, 2011. Check out the download eval once its posted.

Comment: Matt, thanks for that. Was hoping I could find the original community edition still... We did actually purchase the BoundsChecker suite back in the day. The profiler was not part of the suite back then if I recall correctly.

Comment: Historically that could be true. Today the performance profiler is part of the DPS Professional suite, the DP VC++/BoundsChecker suite, the DPS Runtime Analysis SKU, and the DPS Performance Profiler SKU, in decreasing order of price. The VC edition won't do .NET but all the others do along with C++.